How to optimize mysql query result from nodejs with mysql2
I have a query with single table, it has 40k datas and I set the indexing in every table,
I try to execute the query, the query result show less 7 second.
with same query I try to exec in my nodejs project with mysql2
it surprising me that i take more than 40 sec, to get the query result.
how come ?
this below my code
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const configSales = {
  host: "host",
  user: "user",
  password: "password", 
  database: "database",
};
const DBSales = new mysql.createPool(configSales);
const request = await DBSales.promise(); 
let sep = 'select * from sales_report'
const rp = await request.query(sep);
console.log(rp.length,` finish execute here...`)

Why is there such a significant difference in query execution time?

There's no join in the sep query you show here (it's also missing quotes).

Select * from table queries cannot use any index. Fetching 4k rows into node.js does seem to be counterintuitive. The 40 sec you experience is not just the query execution time, but also the fetch time into node.js objects in memory.
